# Class property as a statement in ES6

Tags: javascript, es6-class

In the following code, what is the purpose of writing the class properties as statements (3 commented lines)? Is it property initialization?

```js
 export default class Player extends Camera {
   constructor(opts = {}) {
    super(opts);
    if(opts.target)
      this.setTarget(opts.target);
    this.movie;          // 1
    this.currentFrame;   // 2
    this.displayer;      // 3
    ...
```

[Original Source](https://github.com/artf/cimice/blob/master/src/components/Player.js#L25)

Comment: Maybe they are getters? However i admit that it makes no sense either.

Comment: I see no purpose as there is no value provided to them. I may be useful for devs to know what properties you may find in this class.

Comment: I like to declare all class properties at the beginning of a class/file to make it clear what the available class properties are, would probably have set them to some default value. I think it makes the code easier to maintain no matter which language I am in so do this often

Comment: They were not getters, which was I thought it might be some new language feature introduced in ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do nothing whatsoever in terms of the code itself assuming they aren't defined as getters (they aren't in the code you've quoted). (If they're getters and being called for their side-effects, that would be poor coding on multiple levels... :-) )

But IDEs sometimes infer the properties available on objects created by constructor functions or classes based on what properties are referenced on `this` within the constructor, so the author may have done this to improve the IDE's auto-suggest feature while editing. E.g., they do `const p = new Player()` and the IDE knows, from the constructor code, to offer `movie`, `currentFrame`, and `displayer` when he/she types `p.`. (A better option would be to set them to some appropriate initial value, even if `undefined`; that code won't *create* the properties on the actual object.)

Alternately, the author was just inexperienced with JavaScript and thought he/she had to "declare" the properties in some way, found that doing what you've shown didn't cause an error, and so assumed it was right.

Comment: I don't think the author was inexperienced, so it was probably added for IDE support. Thank you.